# Why after downgrading from Nexus Professional to Nexus OSS it says "Unable to lookup security reals"?

Tags: nexus

After downgrading from Nexus Professional to OSS, Nexus starts but with an exception in [nexus-runtime-oss]/logs/wrapper.log

```
INFO  [jetty-main-1   ] - org.sonatype.security.configuration.source.FileSecurityConfigurationSource - Loading Security configuration from /var/opt/jet/nexus-data/sonatype-work/nexus/conf/security-configuration.xml
ERROR [jetty-main-1   ] - org.sonatype.security.DefaultSecuritySystem - Unable to lookup security realms
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: User-Token-Realm
|      at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
|      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Nexus OSS does not support the "User-Token-Realm" Security Realm.

Edit the sonatype-work/nexus/conf/security-configuration.xml and remove the corresponding line in the realms

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<security-configuration>
  <version>2.0.7</version>
  <anonymousAccessEnabled>true</anonymousAccessEnabled>
  <anonymousUsername>anonymous</anonymousUsername>
  <anonymousPassword>...</anonymousPassword>
  <realms>
    <realm>User-Token-Realm</realm>  //remove this line
    <realm>XmlAuthenticatingRealm</realm>
    <realm>XmlAuthorizingRealm</realm>
  </realms>
  <hashIterations>1024</hashIterations>
</security-configuration>
```